# Your account is not in good standing - Unlisted YouTube videos 

Tags: youtube

I uploaded a video to YouTube that had the name of a TV show in its title. The video itself did not contain any issues.

The video was pulled for copyright infringement. Which is fair enough, I guess.

When I now view my YouTube account details I get the message:

> Your account is not in good standing

This seems to have a side effect to not allowing me to upload unlisted videos anymore. They have to be public or private.

Is there any way I can recover the ability to upload unlisted videos?

Comment: Related Youtube official help article: [Changes to account standing | Youtube Help](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2797387?hl=en)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to threads in the YouTube's help forums, the copyright strikes are permanent and are not removed without filing a [counter-notification](http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?answer=59826)".

Excerpt from the page:

```
If you believe your content was misidentified as infringing, 
you may file a counter-notification. If you did not have all
of the rights to post the material at issue, you MUST NOT 
submit a counter-notification.
```

Good luck!

Comment: The link is broken